# Stack adt python balanced parentheness

Tags: python

Write a function called balanced_brackets().  This function will be passed a string as an input, and you must check that any parentheses or angled brackets in the string, that is: '(', '<', ')' and '>', are correctly balanced.

I am struggling how to get it right and ignore none symbol. Could someone please help me? This is my coding:

```
def balanced_brackets(text):
    s = Stack()
    balanced = True
    index = 0
    while index < len(text) and balanced:
        symbol = text[index]
        if symbol in "(<":
            s.push(symbol)
        else:
            index += 1

        index = index + 1

    if balanced and s.is_empty():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This is the screenshot of output:
[image]

Comment: `if balanced and s.is_empty():`. You never change `balanced` from True, and you never `pop` from `s`, so this condition will always be true if `s` is empty and it will most likely be full unless you get only a series of closing brackets

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of mistakes in your method.

The correct steps should be along the lines of

1. When `(` or `<` is encountered push it onto the stack
2. When`)` or `>` is encountered:

   1. Compare it to the top stack value to see if they match
   2. If they match pop the top value off the stack
   3. If they do not match the string is not balanced

If every encountered `)` and `>` matched the top value on the stack and at the end the stack is empty, the string was balanced.

Comment: I like it. Perfect!

Comment: I quite understand the idea behind, but can you please guide me through it with the code, I am struggling where should i modify my code.